# Does each void level have a specific blueprint?

Tags: warframe

I know that you have to find certain blueprints by going to void missions, but does each type of mission have a different weapon (ex. Exterminate 1 gave me a dakra blueprint, and if I do exterminate 1 again, it will give me a blueprint for another dakra part), or is it random what weapon you will get a bp for (next time I do exterminate 1 it will give me like seer parts or something)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different void missions (extermination, mobile defence, etc) have different loot tables. Each time you finish a mission, one item from the loot tables is chosen as a reward by the RNG gods. A single void mission type's loot table consists always of many weapons' parts and usually, if not always, something else such as forma blueprint.

If you do another exterminate one, you might get another Dakra part, or you might get something else.

[This outdated loot table](http://www.reddit.com/r/Warframe/comments/1fic8o/mission_rewards_drop_tables/) should give you an idea.

Comment: Wow, I wasn't expecting to get an answer so quickly! It's been, what, 2 minutes? This answers my question exactly, and I have to say I wouldn't have thought of this myself. Thank you!

Comment: @TheUgly Sometimes there just happens to be someone, who plays the game and knows the answer, on the site when the question is posted. As simple as that.